# Null Check Operator used on a null value due to provider class

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, flutter-provider, state-management

I'm getting the 'null check operator used on a null value' when I try to access specific screens.

I blocked out my 'user_provider' custom class as well as parts of the code where it's used and it displays normally (no red screen) but without those screens.

This is the custom class

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:purple/models/user.dart';
import 'package:purple/resources/auth_methods.dart';

class UserProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  User? _user;
  final AuthMethods _authMethods = AuthMethods();

  User get getUser => _user!;

  Future<void> refreshUser() async {
    User user = await _authMethods.getUserDetails();
    _user = user;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

I underdertand this could be as a result of the bang operator in line 9 but I'm new to fluttr and have no idea how to go about it.

Comment: Your `getUserDetails` is returning `null` somewhere in your app because you get that error when trying to access `_user`. You need to only access `_user` if it's not `null` ie. `if (getUser != null) {...}` and tell the app what to do if it is null. That's all I can tell you with the amount of code you shared.

Comment: try this.  add ? after User in line 9, like User? get getUser => _user!;

Comment: add ?? and default value for you variable, so its not error

Comment: Have a look at my answer and try to share how you use `UserProvider`.

Answer (score 1):

You should not call `getUser` if it returns null. Maybe you did not load the user from `_authMethods.getUserDetails()`.

So here is an idea, check if user is logged in first then call `getUser`

```dart
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:purple/models/user.dart';
import 'package:purple/resources/auth_methods.dart';

class UserProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  User? _user;
  final AuthMethods _authMethods = AuthMethods();

  User get getUser => _user!;

  bool get isLoggedIn => _user != null; // <---------- added

  Future<void> refreshUser() async {
    User user = await _authMethods.getUserDetails();
    _user = user;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

then in a screen or a widget:

```dart
if (userProvider.isLoggedIn) {
   // TODO: do what you want such as returning user's name
   return userProvider.getUser.name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:purple/models/user.dart';
import 'package:purple/resources/auth_methods.dart';

class UserProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  User _user;
  final AuthMethods _authMethods = AuthMethods();

  User get getUser => _user;

  Future<void> refreshUser() async {
    User user = await _authMethods.getUserDetails();
    _user = user;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```